# Using CORS Still Give Cross Origin Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, node.js, cors

I'm trying to access a node route through angular `$http` using the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module. I've tried a simple

```
app.use(cors());
```

but still get the error. And I've tried adding from [the cors documentation a whitelist of URLs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin)

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
  }
};

app.get('/someroute/:someparam/', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  mymodule.getData(req.params.someparam, function(err, data){
      if (err){
        console.log('error with route', err);
      }else{
        res.json({result: data});
      }
  });
});
```

But I'm still getting the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8888/someroute/undefined. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I thought that using the cors module was meant to avoid this problem. How can I solve?

Comment: I think you also need to allow it server side

Comment: CORS headers need to be set on the server, not the client.

Comment: How on earth are you loading your web app into your browser? Your URL (as quoted in the error message) doesn't appear to have any scheme associated with it at all, and the error message is complaining you aren't using HTTP.

Comment: @Pointy This is all in my `server.js` file, so when I spool up my server with `node server.js` in Terminal, shouldn't that exist server-side?

Comment: @Quentin App is loaded in browser with `app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendfile('./index.html');
});` so I go to localhost:8888 and i see then index page. There's an ng-click on a button on that page which does an `$http` get to the route I showed in the question.

Comment: @thomas OK it wasn't 100% clear that that's what was going on, so that part makes sense at least.

Comment: @thomas — So you load the app by visiting `http://localhost:8888` and then you access `http://localhost:8888/someroute/undefined` with JS? That isn't a cross origin request. I don't understand how that could be generating the error you describe (CORS shouldn't even be a factor).

Comment: @Quentin I think it might be something with Chrome. It's not the first time I have encountered it iirc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your client needs to make a request for the URL

```
http://localhost:8888/someroute/undefined
```

Instead, your client is making a request for

```
localhost:8888/someroute/undefined
```

which the browser interprets as a request for the host `8888` using the scheme `localhost`. However, `localhost` isn't a scheme that Chrome supports for CORS; only things like `http`, `https`, `data` are.

Somewhere, your client-side code does something like

```
xhr.send("localhost:8888/...")
```

but it needs a leading scheme, like `http://` or `https://`.

Note that you get a similar error if you try to request a resource with a `file` or `about` scheme.

Comment: So how can I solve this? I've tried adding `http://` to the beginning of the whitelist URL and the `$http.get()`, but it seemed to get confused about where to look for the route.

Comment: Your client needs to *request* the right thing. Your request possibly isn't even making it to the server. Whether or not it is, Chrome is shutting down the request because you're doing `xhr.send("localhost:8888/...")` somewhere, and Chrome sees that as an illegal `localhost` scheme.

Comment: It was because the parameter I was passing to the route is the location of a directory and I hadn't URI encoded it, so it didn't know where the hell it was going. When I encode it and pass it through the route to the node module, everything is processed and looks to be working great! Thanks for the help!