# Enabled Cross Origin but error still persists

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have enabled CORS in my nodejs server that is using express as a middleware but i am still getting

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

I have tried enabling cors and solutions suggested here 
[Using CORS Still Give Cross Origin Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294494/using-cors-still-give-cross-origin-error)

But it still doesn't work for me.

```
app.use(cors())
app.options('*',cors())
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // authorized headers for preflight requests
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/preflight_request
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();

    app.options('*', (req, res) => {
        // allowed XHR methods  
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        res.send();
    });
});
```

This how i am creating request in front-end `nextjs` app.

```
 const requestBody={
            bnb: address
        }


        let config = {
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }


        axios.post(methods.verify_bnb, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
        //
```

I should be able to make request and server to process it as i have enabled cors but it is still throwing mentioned errors.

Comment: To make sure cors is configured here, please take a look here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html . Are you getting 503 error code? I saw once how it was interpretaded as cors error in chrome browser - in my example i got this when server had problems with database call when processing request.

Comment: I did followed instructions from link provided for this app but still no use. No i am not getting 503 error either. It is not producing error on local environment.

Comment: did you try using cors like this ? const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors()) , I think right now you are setting cors and then overwriting those settings. Or look here if want to allow it for specific routes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o

Comment: Yes i am using this config. I have removed the other ones but error still persists. It is worth mentioning that i have deployed server on google compute engine. I am able to interact it with postman with http but on app it gives error of blocked mixed content so i have converted it to https, it doesn't work with postman but app doesn't create that error but cors error

Comment: Did you check google compute engine logs?

Comment: Yes i did. But i solved the issue by deploying front end and server both on the same compute engine.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my front-end on zeit and server on compute engine. This was giving me this error, as soon as i deployed front-end on the same compute engine, it worked fine. I am not sure if thats the right implementation but CORS error is not producing anymore